# Exsheets: Print solutions in footnote

Tags: footnotes, exsheets

I'm trying to display the solutions to questions in a footnote. So far I have tried two approaches. The easy one is to simply wrap the solution environment in a `\footnotetext`, which works reasonably well (i still have to find a good footnote command which won't typeset any marks, but that's another story). But i'd rather have a nicer approach, which works using the pre-/post-hooks for the solution environment. Here's a minimal example of what i've tried so far:

```
\documentclass[paper=a4, BCOR=1cm, DIV=11]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[headings=runin]{exsheets}

\SetupExSheets{
  solution/print=true,
  solution/headings=inline,
  solution/pre-hook=\footnotetext[1]\begingroup,
  solution/post-hook=\endgroup
}
\begin{document}

\begin{question}
  The question
\end{question}

\begin{solution}
  The solution
\end{solution}

\end{document}
```

This will kind of work, but spits out the following errors:

```
! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
\scr@saved@footnotetext ...tbox }\color@endgroup }

l.43 \end{solution}
```

My guess is, i don't have a correct understanding of how the hooks or the begin/endgroup macros work? Does anyone have an elegant solution to this?

**Edit:**

Clarification of what I'm currently using:

```
\newcommand{\solutions}[1]{
  \begingroup
  \renewcommand{\thefootnote}{}
  \newcommand{\task}{\item}
  \footnotetext{
    Solutions for Exercise \thequestion:
    \begin{inparaenum}[\itshape a)\upshape]
      #1
    \end{inparaenum}
  }
  \endgroup
}
```

This uses the question counter to automatically place an appropriate footnote, but I'd rather have an approach with the actual `exsheet` solution environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update: with version 0.18:**

Since version 0.18 (2015/02/09) which has been uploaded to CTAN on 2015/02/10 and will be available in TeX Live and MiKTeX in a few days the solution is as follows:

- Set the heading style for solutions to `inline` or `inline-nr` or a equivalent instance.
- Redefine `\exsheetsprintsolution`. This macro is used for every solution. It has two mandatory arguments, the first for the heading, the second for the solution body. Its default definition is equivalent to

  ```
  \newcommand\exsheetsprintsolution[2]{#1#2}
  ```
- In order to get footnotes without numbers I use the `bigfoot` package and declare a new footnote type and then redefine the corresponding »`\thefootnote`« to print nothing.

A complete example:

```
\documentclass[paper=a4, BCOR=1cm, DIV=11]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[headings=runin]{exsheets}[2015/02/09]
\usepackage{bigfoot}

% \DeclareNewFootnote{default} % if `normal' footnotes should be printed first
\DeclareNewFootnote{solution}
\renewcommand\thefootnotesolution{}

\renewcommand\exsheetsprintsolution[2]{\footnotesolution{#1#2}}

\SetupExSheets{
  headings-format   = \bfseries ,% no \normalsize!
  solution/print    = true,
  solution/headings = inline
}
\begin{document}

\begin{question}
  The question
\end{question}
\begin{solution}
  The solution
\end{solution}

\begin{question}
  Another question
\end{question}
\begin{solution}
  Another solution
\end{solution}

\end{document}
```

**Original answer (with version 0.17):**

This is a hack because it uses knowledge about usage and definition of an internal command from `exsheets` (`\__exsheets_print_solution:nnnn`) which cannot be relied upon. (On my todo list now: provide an interface for tasks like this...)

In order to get footnotes without numbers I use the `bigfoot` package and declare a new footnote type and then redefine the corresponding »`\thefootnote`« to print nothing.

```
\documentclass[paper=a4, BCOR=1cm, DIV=11]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[headings=runin]{exsheets}
\usepackage{bigfoot}

% \DeclareNewFootnote{default} % if `normal' footnotes should be printed first
\DeclareNewFootnote{solution}
\renewcommand\thefootnotesolution{}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Npn \solutionnote #1 \exsheets_h_or_vspace:N
  {
    \footnotesolution{#1}
    \use_none:n
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\SetupExSheets{
  headings-format     = \bfseries ,% no \normalsize!
  solution/print      = true,
  solution/headings   = inline,
  solution/pre-hook   = \solutionnote ,
  question/skip-below = -.5\baselineskip % skip back a little
}
\begin{document}

\begin{question}
  The question
\end{question}
\begin{solution}
  The solution
\end{solution}

\begin{question}
  Another question
\end{question}
\begin{solution}
  Another solution
\end{solution}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: In the next version there will be a more convenient way to achieve the desired result. I'll update the answer once the new version is available

Comment: Awesome. This type of display appears to be the norm in some schools for math exercises, since the results are usually something small like `x=2` and meant as a control for the pupil.

Comment: @Richard in this case you might even want to have a closer look at `bigfoot` and maybe use `\DeclareNewFootnote[para]{solution}`

Comment: Also `inline-nr` seems to be a good choice for the solutions IMHO.

Comment: I updated the answer with the solution for v0.18